# Simpleform order association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

While using simpleform how do I order the select options with an association? I have something like this:

```
= f.association :color
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can pass a `collection` option to association:

```
= f.association :color, collection: Color.order('created_at ASC')
```